# como dar de alta nuevo evento en google calendar con php

Tags: php, api, calendar

Tengo u a clase con la que identifico a los usuarios con google, que se llama GoogleAuth, alli tengo un constructor que recibe al mismo cliente, cuando se logra identificar se inserta un evento en el calendario correctamente, aqui el codigo

```
 public function evento(){
    $eventName = "Nombre del evento";
    $eventDescription = "Descripción del evento";
    $eventStartTime = "2019-05-30T13:00"; //Hora inicial del evento
    $eventEndTime = "2019-05-30T14:00"; // //Hora final del evento

    //$_SESSION['aux']=$this->client;
    $client= $this->client;

    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {    

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
      'summary' => $eventName,
      'description' => $eventDescription,
      'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => $eventStartTime.':00-06:00'
      ),
      'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => $eventEndTime.':00-06:00'
      ),  
      'reminders' => array(
        'useDefault' => FALSE,
        'overrides' => array(
          array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
          array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
        ),
      ),
    ));

    $calendarId = 'primary';
    $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
    printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
    echo "HOLAS";
}
}
```

el detalle esta es que no se como llamarlo desde otra clase externa, es decir, tengo un archivo en php con la función de alta nuevo evento, el cual me permite guardar el evento en una base de datos, pero antes de so yo quiero que se sincronice en google calendar

```
switch($opcion){
    case 'registrar':
        registrar($identificador, $tipoevento, $fecha, $hora, $observaciones, $conexion);  
    break;

    default:
        $informacion["respuesta"]="OPCION_VACIA";
        echo json_encode($informacion);
    break;
}
```

Nada mas que no se como llamar al evento sin reiniciar el constructor, ayuda por favor